# Apply footer to PDF on the fly

Tags: java, pdf

I have code that applies a footer to all PDFs. It works fine when I execute the code with a source and destination folder. Now I need to adapt this to a printing workflow, where I can call to an external script, that applies the footer to all pdf's pages when this workflow is running.  The flow is simple:

(1) The PDFs are submited to a printer that has a workflow working behind.

(2) This workflow converts the file to PDF and sends it to a virtual printer until the user release the job.

(3) After the convertion to PDF the external script is called, so the source is the submited job and the destination is the printer

This is the code that I'm using:

```
package com.itextpdf.stamp;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.File;

public class Footer {
    public static final String DEST = "c:/output/pdf/Cover.pdf";
    public static final String SRC = "c:/input/Cover.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new Footer().addFooter(DEST);
    }

    protected void addFooter(String dest) throws Exception {
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DEST));
         //adding the footer ...           
    }
}
```

Comment: The flow is not clear, but consider passing source and destination in `args` - if they exist use them - otherwise use the constant values.

Comment: hi Andrew S apologise about that, the flow are very simple, the PDF are submited to a printer that have aworkflow working behind, this workflow convert the file to PDF and sen to a virtual printer until the user release the job.After the convertion to PDF is when the external script is called, so the source is the submited job and the destination is the printer ...Hope that clarify.

Comment: The workflow is still not clear. Try to reduce your description to the relevant parts. If you describe all steps to it with numbers and describe in- and output. E.g. (1) PDF is submitted to a printer (In: PDF out: ?) [Question: How do you submit it?) (2) Convert the PDF to a PDF via virtual printer (in: PDF out: PDF) [Comment: PDF to PDF doesn't make sense]. (3) External script is called (in: pdf out:?) [Where is the script called? What kind of script?... Too many unknown issues here to give an answer....

Comment: @Lonzak, I will try to explain.  This printer is configured inside a accounting application who controlls all printing steps, i.e. identify the user,etc, and also have the possibility to invoke external Jscripts to add external information, so, I need to modify the script in order to add some information to the footer of all pages without saving the PDF to a folder.  I'll describe the workflow process on the next comment

Comment: Example of the workflow:  1. PDF is sumitted to the printer - file -> print  2. The workflow analyze the PDF in order to indentify the number of pages, if is color/BK, set price, etc.  3. The workflow invoke an external script, (this script) to add some information on footer.  4. The pdf are sent to the printer and printed.  Hope this clarify a little bit.Carlos

Comment: So I need to replace this part of code     <code>public static final String DEST = "c:/output/pdf/Cover.pdf";
    public static final String SRC = "c:/input/Cover.pdf"; </code>  with any args that could aply the footer wher the pdf are handl by the workflow